# Xamarin editable UITextField in UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin, uitextfield

i want to insert an editable textfield in uiview.
I've used

```
UIView view = new UIView ();
StreetNameInput = new UITextField (new CoreGraphics.CGRect (0, 0, 160f, 40f));
view.Add (StreetNameInput);
view.UserInteractionEnabled = StreetNameInput.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
```

but when application starts, the textfield is not editable.

Can you help me please?

Thank you,
regards.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in UIView creation, i need to specify dimension in follow way

```
UIView view = new UIView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0,0,320,150));
```